# Uri.parse() adds null before the given Url

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

I'm passing a Google maps Url to initiate a search using the Maps app and everything used to work fine. After importing my project on my linux machine, the `mapIntent.resolveActivity()` part is `null` despite the device having google maps and the `gmINtentUri` is `nullhttps://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=Spilia%20Beach`. I'm guessing this is caused due to the extra `null` part in front of the Url. What causes this? It wasn't happening on my Windows machine.

**Edit**: I figured out that the `gmIntentUri`'s `null` value at the beginning of the string was due to this `parcel.writeString(finalMapSearchUrl);`. I'll submit the answer later on.

```
@OnClick(R.id.show_in_map_button) void openMap() {
    Uri gmIntentUri = Uri.parse(placeObject.getMapSearchUrl()); // Create a Uri from a string. Use the result to create an Intent
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,gmIntentUri);
    // Make the Intent explicit by settings the Google Maps package
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    // Verify that there is an app available to receive the intent
    if(mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(mapIntent); // if the result is non-null there is at least one app that can handle the intent
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"Error resolving Activity for map Intent in openMap(), [Uri = " + gmIntentUri + "].");
        Log.d(TAG,"mapIntent.resolveActivity() = " + mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()));
    }
}
```

Here is the PlaceObject.java class that contains the getMapSearchUrl() :

```
public class PlaceObject implements Parcelable {

    private static final String TAG = PlaceObject.class.getSimpleName();

    // Using int so that the values can be accessed via R.string etc.
    private int name;
    private int description;
    private String locationDistance;
    private int category;
    private static final String baseMapSearchUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query="; // Base url for launching a Map activity with a Search Intent
    private String finalMapSearchUrl = "";

    PlaceObject(int name, int description, int category , String locationDistance, String mapUrlParam) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.locationDistance = locationDistance;
        this.category = category;
        finalMapSearchUrl += baseMapSearchUrl + Uri.encode(mapUrlParam);
        Log.d(TAG,"Final map URL : " + finalMapSearchUrl);
    }

    private PlaceObject(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readInt();
        description = in.readInt();
        locationDistance = in.readString();
        category = in.readInt();
        finalMapSearchUrl = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<PlaceObject> CREATOR = new Creator<PlaceObject>() {
        @Override
        public PlaceObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new PlaceObject(in);
        }

        @Override
        public PlaceObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PlaceObject[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(name);
        parcel.writeInt(description);
        parcel.writeString(locationDistance);
        parcel.writeInt(category);
        parcel.writeString(finalMapSearchUrl);
    }

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getLocationDistance() {
        return locationDistance;
    }

    public int getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getMapSearchUrl() {
        return finalMapSearchUrl;
    }
}
```

P.S: `mapUrlParam` in the `PlaceObject()` is a simple `String` that according to Google, needs to be encoded before using it due to spaces etc.

Comment: Please check the `placeObject.getMapSearchUrl()` method. Maybe the `null` is already there and that should be modified instead of the attached code part.

Comment: @Blehi thank you, just added that part of the code. I honestly don't see how `null` could be added at the beginning of the string, could it have something to do with the `Parcelable` interface? I've never used it before so i might have messed something in the constructor. Maybe the `finalMapSearchUrl = in.readString()` ?

Comment: What do you see in the log regarding this: `Log.d(TAG,"Final map URL : " + finalMapSearchUrl);`? Maybe in the constructor instead of `finalMapSearchUrl +=` you should use `finalMapSearchUrl =`

Comment: I've already applied both of these changes in my code and figured out that the `finalMapSearchUrl` is ok within the constructor but when the `getMapSearchUrl()` is called, it is empty. Any ideas on where the value gets lost?

Comment: I think the best would be to debug your app step by step or put a lot of `Log.d()` where the value can change. I see no other option, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the `gmIntentUri`'s null value at the beginning of the `string` was due to this `parcel.writeString(finalMapSearchUrl);` As far as the issue in the comments, i'll make a different post about it.